# What are the required permissions to view Delivery Reports in Exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

According to the [Mail Flow Permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638213%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) page the following roles are required to do Message Tracking:

- Organization Management
- Records Management
- Recipient Management

The domain admin has these roles assigned to it. Yet when I login to EAC I am still not able to view delivery reports for other users. On the other hand I can see the admin's reports and I can login to OWA with my own user and see reports for myself too.

Clearly this is a permissions issue but I don't know what more I need. I'm probably just not noticing the instructions somewhere in the docs.

Below is a screenshot:
[image: What my "Delivery Report" looks like.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is user error. I discovered that I was looking at my permissions with the wrong cmdlet. I was using Get-ManagementRoleAssignment and should have been using:

```
Get-RoleGroupMember "Organization Management"
Get-RoleGroupMember "Records Management"
Get-RoleGroupMember "Recipient Management"
```

I've corrected the missing permissions and, as expected, everything is working after a logout/login.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to add the administrator to Organization Management or Records Management.

The solution to the problem is to ensure that the administrator is Mailbox Enabled in Exchange.